# Localizing iOS airprint dialog

Tags: ios, localization

I'm developing an iPhone app for italian language.

I set the language in the info.plist but seems not to work for some controls as AirPrint dialogs. The simulator and the iPhone are set to italian language but the dialog is in english...

I'm developing the app for iOS5 & iOS6

[image: info.plist]

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: A brief search doesn't find anything special about this control and internationalization.  (In fact, it finds nothing at all.)

Comment: Yeah, I googled too... But the problem is that every other app I'm using localize it correctly. In my app it stays in english, so I think I need a more general setting somewhere for it to be localized... The real question is, then: "Have I did all the correct steps in my .plist file to localize my app?"

Comment: I wonder if there was something wrong with a build step that caused the localization database to be omitted for that class?

Comment: Don't know, it's my first iPhone app :P is there only the plist step in the 1st screenshot to localize the app?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you much.  Here I have other guys who worry about localization issues for me.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
I created the "Localization" key in my plist file, then I removed all the MainStoryboard references in my project and I reimported the storyboard from the it.lproj folder.

It works now.

Comment: Good to hear!  We're just beginning to use the print protocol here for some apps and I was afraid there might be localization issues.